# Short story about English Language Transformation?

Tags: short-stories, languages, story-identification

I read a short short SF story in the early 80's (I think it was an Asimov collection).

The story wasn't more than 5 pages in a paperback and conjectured what English would look like in the future with the words starting in recognizable English and ending with gibberish that the reader could decipher because of reading the story.

I remember the thrill and whit but cannot find the story anywhere.  Does anybody out there know it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [***Meihem In Ce Klasrum***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57114) written in 1946 by Dolton Edwards and originally published in '[The Astounding Science Fiction Anthology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Astounding_Science_Fiction_Anthology)'. The story is a classic example of [*futurespeak*](http://www.ansible.co.uk/sfx/sfx177.html).

There's a full copy of the text [here](http://www.waynesthisandthat.com/meihem.htm).

> Because we are still bearing some of the scars of our brief skirmish
> with II-B English, it is natural that we should be enchanted by Mr.
> George Bernard Shaw's current campign for a simplified alphabet.
> Obviously, as Mr. Shaw points out, English spelling is in much need of
> a general overhauling and streamlining. However, any changes requiring
> a large expenditure of mental effort in the near future would cause us
> to view with some apprehension the possibility of some day receiving a
> morning paper printed in - to us - Greek.

later

> In ce seim maner, bai meiking eakh leter hav its own sound and cat
> sound only, we kould shorten ce langauge stil mor. In 1952 we would
> elimineit ce "y"; cen in 1953 we kould us ce letter to indikeit the
> "sh" sound, cerbai klarifaiing words laik yugar and yur, as wel as
> redusing bai wun mor leter al words laik "yut," "yore," and so forc.

Comment: Interesting! I thought this sounded similar to a piece by Mark Twain, but it turns out that one was not really written by Mark Twain at all! This short story you mention [might be behind some other falsely attributed "spelling reform" stories](http://www.spellingsociety.org/journals/j31/satires.php).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @ThomLehman - https://www.lds.org/bc/content/shared/content/images/gospel-library/magazine/friendlp.nfo:o:2970.jpg